# Need do help to delete something with Ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

So i need to delete the row from a table but as well the data, and its only deleting the row.

This is the part of the table with the data

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicAddRemove">  
            <tr>
            <th>Componente</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
    
            <th>Entregue</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($componentes_projeto as $cp)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$cp->Componente->nomecomponente}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{$cp->quantidade_utilizada}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($cp->entregue)
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="moreFields[0][Entregue]" checked/>
                        @else
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="moreFields[0][Entregue]"/>
                        @endif
                        
                      
                   
                    <td class="text-center">
                       {{--  <form role="form" action="/componente_projeto/{{$cp->id }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE') --}}
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-2 animate-up-2 remove-tr " data-id="{{ $cp->id }}" >Eliminar</button> 
                           {{-- <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a> --}}
                        {{-- </form> --}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            <tr>
```

This is my ajax function

```
 $(".remove-tr").click(function(){
                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                
                var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

                 $.ajax(
                     {
                         url: "componente_projetos/"+cp,
                          type: 'DELETE',
                       data: {
                         "cp": id,
                    "_token": token,
                      },
                     success: function (response){
                      $(cp).remove;
                      }
                      });

                            });
```

This is my controller

```
 public function destroy(componente_projeto $componente_projeto)
{
    //
    $componente_projeto->delete();
    
   return redirect('/componente_projetos');
}
```

and this is my route

Route::delete('/componente_projetos/{cp}/', [App\Http\Controllers\ComponenteProjetoController::class, 'destroy']);

Comment: `url: "componente_projetos/"+cp,` first,  where are you getting cp from, and what is it. Also how do you expect to hit the function destroy in your controller. I see no mention of it in your ajax.

Comment: What's that variable `cp` inside your JS code supposed to be, where does that come from?

Comment: Please try to remove parent 'tr' after the successful ajax call. Because after deleting of the parent element, the id can be null.

Comment: cp is coming from here  @foreach ($componentes_projeto as $cp)